# How to select a whole column or row in a formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to select a whole column for a formula in excel.
I know I can do this, for example:

`=AVERAGE(B4:B54)`

which would give me the average of the cells from B4 to B54 but I want to reference the whole B column.
How can I do this?

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to be for programming questions. Software problems can be discussed at Superuser.com

Comment: @RedHood148 I'm working on this problem too. This question is welcome on superuser. If it is not posted there I'll post one similar to it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To reference an entire column in Excel, use this syntax:

`=AVERAGE(B:B)`

Comment: what if you don't want to select first row in this range ... ?

Comment: @DisHonest you can do this:
=AVERAGE(B2:B)

Comment: @LawrenceMok yours seems not to work

Comment: `=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B:B,1,0,ROWS(B:B)-1))`. `OFFSET` moves the range down by 1 row in the formula, and reduces the size of the range by 1 (size reduction is necessary, otherwise it will be an invalid range).