# In Google Sheets how to reference infinite rows in column?

Tags: google-sheets

If I want to reference a span of rows I can do something like `A1:A100`. If I want to lock the column/row I can use `$`; `$A1:$A100`.

Is there notation or a symbol that represents an *infinite* range, or every row that could possibly be in a column?

Something like `$A!` or whatever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a whole column or row in a formula in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870754/how-to-select-a-whole-column-or-row-in-a-formula-in-excel)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To reference an entire column you can use, for example:

```
 Sum(A:A)
```

So I guess the syntax you are looking for is `A:A`

Equally, if you want to use every piece of data in a column excluding the first, lets say 2, rows you can use `A3:A` (in google sheets only)

Comment: Anyone had luck doing this where the value is in a separate sheet? What I thought would be obvious isn't working. `=sum('Sheet Name'!P:P)`

Comment: to reference another sheet, starting from one cell to the end of the column, I have to use eg `=sum(Sheet!P:Sheet!P9999` or for example the corresponding relative/absolute variants, optionally starting from a specific row, eg `=sum(Sheet!$P2:Sheet!$P9999)` etc etc, main point being to just specify end of the column as some big number like 9999 or such

Answer (score 41):

Google sheets is more flexible, you can use the syntax

```
=Sum(A2:A)
```

or even

```
=Sum(A2:C)
```

You can also do the same with rows e.g.

```
=Sum(B2:2)
```

**Edit**

In answer to @Trevor's question, how do you specify a range from (say) B2 to the last cell of the last row of the sheet, for a sheet of default size (A1 to Z1000) the answer is trivially

```
=sum(B2:Z)
```

or

```
=sum(B2:1000)
```

but then as soon as you add extra columns or rows this is incorrect.

As far as I know there is no shorter alternative to using address and indirect:

```
=sum(indirect("B2:"&address(rows(A:A),columns(1:1))))
```

or offset:

```
=sum(offset(B2,0,0,rows(A:A)-row(B2)+1,columns(1:1)-column(B2)+1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Too simple for me to even try :)

Comment: Anyone had luck doing this where the value is in a separate sheet?

Comment: Addendum, what I thought would be obvious isn't working.

`=sum('Sheet Name'!P:P)`

Comment: It works for me, unless the numbers in column P are formatted as text?

Comment: What about selecting a range that starts in cell B2 and ends at the last cell of the last row in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Good question - will add to my answer.