# Insert Formula into Entire Column via Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I'm attempting to insert the formula `=INDIRECT(\"G\"&ROW()) - INDIRECT(\"J\"&ROW())` (which subtracts `J` from `G`) into column `K` using Google Sheets API v4. However, instead of inserting the formula into one cell I want to insert it into all current/future rows in the given column.

To do this I'm using the following code:

```
public void updateSingleColumnAndParseInput(String spreadsheetId, String range, List<List<Object>> rowData) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{

    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT)).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();


    ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();

    valueRange.setRange(range); 

    valueRange.setValues(rowData);
    valueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS"); // "COLUMNS" //"ROWS" (both values give same result)

    List<ValueRange> oList = new ArrayList<>();
    oList.add(valueRange);

    Update update = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange);
    update.setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED"); // USER_ENTERED (values will be parsed)
    HttpResponse values = update.buildHttpRequest().execute();

}
```

I'm calling this method using this code:

```
updateSingleColumnAndParseInput("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "K2:K", dataList);
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47756504/8814573) and [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/NMlubHkdNQY) response I'm expecting the formula to be inserted into all current and future rows of column K but after executing this code only the second row (K2) is being updated.

Comment: the formula itself works flawlessly, it's only updating all rows in column that's an issue

Comment: What's the issue with @pnuts formula?

Comment: 1) What happens if you bound the range, i.e. `K2:K10`, 2) What happens if you omit `valueRange.setRange(range)`, and 3) How large is your `rowData`?

Comment: @tehhowch **1)** same result, only first row is updated **2)** range must be added directly to `service.spreadsheets().values().update()` as parameter so not possible to skip **3)** rowData contains 1 value (the formula) (if I try adding more than one value I get exception: `Requested writing within range [Sheet1!K2:K], but tried writing to column [L]`) Thanks

Comment: @S.O.S re: 2) note that I did not ask you to omit using it in the call, only omit adding it to the `ValueRange`, because you are passing it in both, and if it is in the `ValueRange` it can have meaning during certain requests. Re 3) you get that error because your `majorDimension` is rows and you made the inner list have two values. Either change the major dimension to columns and keep adding to the inner, or add additional `List<Object>` instead of `Object` to it

Comment: @tehhowch 2) Understood. I did that but it didn't change the result 3) changing to columns does not change the outcome.. Thanks!