# How can I sum a row that keeps adding columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know how to sum a column that keeps adding rows e.g. =SUM(b$2:b).  But I can't figure out how to do the same for rows that keep adding columns.  Also, (not sure if this is important, but) I like to add columns on the left, so the newest column is always F, and the older columns keep going down the alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to reference a row: see Tom Sharpe's answer here (see the 3rd formula): [In Google Sheets how to reference infinite rows in column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756457/in-google-sheets-how-to-reference-infinite-rows-in-column/47756569#47756569)

If you want to insert rows at the left, we can use the INDIRECT Function to fix the starting cell while the ending cell is a relative reference. Here's the formula: (This assumes that the formula is at the right of F)

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("F1"):F1)
```

As you add new columns, the F1 reference will adjust to G1, H1 and so on, but the starting cell will be fixed to F1.

If the Formula will be at the left of F, then we can just write:

```
=SUM(F1:1)
```

Comment: I put the indirect function to the left of F and it still worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.  It's exactly what I was looking for.  I have other numbers that I don't want summed that are to the left of F and so the indirect works exactly how I want.  It adds everything in the row from column F and to the right.

Answer (score 0):

for column:

```
=SUM(B2:B)
```

for row:

```
=SUM(B2:2)
```